# Bad for clutch to accelerate with high rpms?

Tags: manual-transmission

I'm aware that launching a car with manual transmission, i.e. rev up and then release the clutch, could potentially cause a bit clutch wear.

But let's assume you start revving up from 1st gear - for a petrol engine - revving up to about 5000 rpm and then quickly changing gear to 2st, will it also cause clutch wear?

I've done this a few times and try to do it rarely. I - think - it's not really the same as standing still because the *difference* in rpm and the actual car speed will be a lot less than if you're actually not moving at all.

See this video as reference: https://youtu.be/54I5RU-RNhQ

Answer (score 1):

Clutch wear occurs whenever you engage the clutch (ie. release the pedal) while there is a difference of rotation of the gearbox input shaft and the flywheel (ie. difference in rotation of the two parts connected by the clutch). During the clutch engagement the difference of speed is gradually overcome by friction.

High revolutions themselves don't automatically mean high clutch wear when changing gears. It only depends on how close you can get to the sweet spot when releasing the pedal, that the engine speed dropped just to the revolutions that match current car speed and the new gear.

Comment: The gearbox output shaft and the axles are always connected with the same ratio - that of the final drive / differential. You mean the difference in speed between the flywheel and the gearbox input shaft - which are the parts connected by the clutch...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put shock load on the clutch, it won't matter much how high the RPM is at which you shift. Shock load comes from snap changes where you throw the gear lever and let the clutch pedal spring back unassisted. In a low powered car, that increases clutch wear. In a high powered car, it can strip the teeth right off your gears.

Comment: it's more likely to rip the centre out of the clutch....